# Confusion regarding the difference between Definite and Indefinite Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So, as we have been taught, the difference between Definite and Indefinite Integration is that Definite integration has limits and Indefinite Integration doesn't have limits. But, say the definite integral is,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx$$ why would it be any different than just integrating it normally as,

$$\int f(x) dx$$

If the bounds themselves in a definite integral are infinite what makes it any different to an indefinite integral.

Comment: the first is a number (assuming the improper integral converges). The second is some silly notation for a specific collection of functions. Different things have different notations. Also what do you think ‘just integrating it normally’ means?

Comment: As in, integrating it without limits.